# Is there a way to block some Excel cells for input after a submit button has been clicked?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel macro, in which after I fill some information I click a Submit button and the file is send over email. What I need is that in the process between the submit function started and the email is send, the file is blocked for previous editing.
Any help would be great, thanks.

I have tried the following code but it does not work

```
Set MyRange = Intersect(Range("J6:J7"), Target)
    If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Sheet").Unprotect Password:="123"
        MyRange.Locked = True
        Sheets("Sheet").Protect Password:="123"
    End If
```

Comment: Exactly what does "it does not work" stand for? What are you expecting, vs what is happening? Is the intersecting range not locked?

Comment: There's a bunch of information missing here...

Comment: great reply, thanks! It does not work stands for: if I put that block of code it does not do anything... What I am excpecting is that after I submit the file, all the cells are blocked so whoever gets the email does not edit any of the information

Comment: We had a user create a pretty decent approach to this. He created a "Very Hidden" sheet in his file which only had the words "PLEASE WAIT - PROCESSING" on it in a big bold font.  He would set the sheet to "Visible" and then set the rest of the sheets to "Very Hidden".  Then he would execute his code, with the "PLEASE WAIT - PROCESSING" sheet displayed for "user entertainment".  Once the code was completed, he switched all the sheets back to their original Visibility settings.  Would an approach like this work for you?

Comment: I do not think so or at least I do not see how that would help me. Imagine you have a form and you fill it up, then you send it over email. so another person receives it but can not edit it, just can see it. that is what I am trying to acomplish. to block the cells for later editing

Comment: So what you're after is for the person receiving the file to not be able to edit the specific cells.  Is your code in file being sent?  If it is, then you leave the Unprotect password exposed by accessing the VBA editor (unless you password protect your module).  Have you confirmed that the "Locked" property cells on that need to be protected is set to True?  Also, is there a reason that this file can't be sent as a PDF?  If you're looking for having a non-editable file, then Adobe is usually your best option.

Comment: I did not think of the Adobe aproach since the received file has also a review button for accept ar declined the information on the file

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you want to do. So you have a excel file opened for Person A to edit, upon clicking submit, you want such excel file to be sent to Person B to review without ability to edit. And Person B has to decide either accept or decline. so I guess if Accept, the excel file will be sent Again and if Decline then nothing happen?

Comment: Correct. So far that process is made. I am just failling in blocking the edition from person B. That whole process mentioned is done actually. If accepted, the information on the file is saved on a database, that is way I want to prevent from editing the original file. Accept and Decline are both buttons on the file. I know it is really a mess, but I am working over somebody elses work who did not document anything

Comment: Is "Sheet" the correct name of the worksheet you are protecting?  It seems a little odd to use that as a name since Excel uses a default naming convention of "Sheet#" so having a worksheet named "Sheet" just seems a little unusual to me.  To make sure that you are using the correct worksheet, try using "MyRange.Worksheet" instead of Sheets("Sheet").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`, I changed `MyRange.Locked = True` to `Cells.Locked = True` so that your entire worksheet is protected.

The expected result is that whenever a change in either J6 or J7 will trigger protection for the entire worksheet.

```
Set MyRange = Intersect(Range("J6:J7"), Target)
    If Not MyRange Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Sheet").Unprotect Password:="123"
        Cells.Locked = True
        Sheets("Sheet").Protect Password:="123"
    End If
```

If you are not using Worksheet_Change event then I changed your condition to test the cell whether it has value.

```
        If Len(Range("J6").Text) <> 0 Or Len(Range("J7").Text) <> 0 Then
            Sheets("Sheet").Unprotect Password:="123"
            Cells.Locked = True
            Sheets("Sheet").Protect Password:="123"
        End If
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it know and let you know if it works

Comment: Why not just take a simple approach and protect the sheet prior to sending it instead of doing it when the user attempts to edit a cell?  It seems like you're making it far more complicated than you need to.

Comment: I just did it that way, when the user sends it, it gets the lock I need.